# How to take count based on different where conditions in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I am trying to count `tickets` based on different where conditions . For which I am using four different queries but same model. Can I do that in one query?

```
        $openTickets = Ticket::where('status',1)->count();
        $pending = Ticket::where('status',2)->count();
        $unAssigned = Ticket::where('agent_id',null)->count();
        $unResolved = Ticket::whereNotIn('status',[3,4])->count();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ticket::selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS open_tickets')
      ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS pending_tickets')
      ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN agent_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS unassigned_tickets')
      ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN status NOT IN (3,4) THEN 1 END) AS unresolved_tickets')
      ->first();
```

You can of course resolve the multiple queries with this query. We can use conditional cases and count.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum up conditionals but will need lots of raw parts in your query:

```
$result = DB::table('tickets')->whereIn('status', [1,2])->orWhereNull('agent_id')->orWhereNotIn('status', [3,4]) // This is to filter out the things we don't care about
->select([
   DB::raw('SUM(IF(status = 1, 1,0)) as countOpen'),
   DB::raw('SUM(IF(status = 2, 1,0)) as countPending'),
   DB::raw('SUM(IF(agent_id IS NULL, 1,0)) as countUnassigned'),
   DB::raw('SUM(IF(status NOT IN (3,4), 1,0)) as countUnresolved'),
])->first()
$openTickets = $result->countOpen;
$pending = $result->countPending;
$unAssigned = $result->countUnassigned;
$unResolved = $result->countUnresolved;
```